# AWS ELB Classic Load Balancer works but Network Load Balancer does not

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-eks

I am using EKS in my Amazon Web Services cluster and I want to deploy a service using a Load Balancer. The YAML I am using has the following annotations on it:

```yaml
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
```

If I create the service using this YAML, it appears as created, the pods are detected and I get a public URL to access to. If I check the Load Balancer at EC2 it appears as healthy and ready. However, when I try to reach the URL it takes forever, literally. It keeps loading and loading and I get no timeout, no DNS error, no message.

On the other hand, if I remove these annotations and update the service, a new Load Balancer is deployed and it works perfectly. The only difference is that the old one appears as a Network Load Balancer and this one appears as a Classic Load Balancer. Even further, if I manually "upgrade" the Classic Load Balancer from the AWS Web UI, a new NLB is created and it works perfectly.

Why can't I make it work directly? What should I check?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you correct syntax by refering [this](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.1/guide/service/annotations/) ?

Comment: @amitd Where do you see the problem? Both "nlb" and "0.0.0.0/0" are detected as strings.

Comment: So, after two days with this problem, leaving it for hours running, changing basically everything a lot of times and running a lot of tests, it decided to work just now. I changed nothing but I am going to accept it as it is.

Comment: `aws-load-balancer-internal` is of type `boolean`